# Undefined name 'contact' - Flutter toJson Map in Stateful widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've created a map yet am having difficulty accessing the variable 'contact' within a stateful widget. I'm not sure where else to declare `final Contact contact;` .

The Contact model file.

```
class Contact {
int rating;
String name;
String location;
int phoneNumber;
String instagram;
int birthday;
String notes;

Contact(this.name, this.phoneNumber, this.location, this.rating,
this.instagram, this.birthday, this.notes);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'Name': name,
    'PhoneNumber': phoneNumber,
    'Location': location,
    'Rating': rating,
    'Instagram': instagram,
    'Birthday': birthday,
    'Notes': notes,
  };
```

Where `final Contact contact;`  is currently declared

```
class NewContact extends StatefulWidget {
NewContact({Key key, @required this.contact}) : super(key: key);
final Contact contact;

@override
NewContactState createState() => NewContactState();
}

class NewContactState<T extends NewContact> extends State<T> {
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance; //...etc
```

Where the Map is being called

```
 await db
                  .collection("userData")
                  .doc(uid)
                  .collection("Contacts")
                  .add(contact.toJson());
```

Error = Undefined name 'contact'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `contact` is defined in the class that extends statful widget, `NewContact`, and you want to access it's corresponding state class `NewContactState`, you should call it like this `widget.contact.toJson()`.